# How to set which app i.e. Instagram to open downloaded file?

Tags: reactjs, imagedownload

If this is the way I am downloading an image:

```
<a
  onClick={(e) => {
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = `/t44-post-cover/${organizationShortId}-${programId}`;
    a.download = `${organizationShortId}-${programId}`;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
  }}
>
  Insta
</a>
```

Can I set, user should open it with Instagram?

Comment: What programming language are you using? [edit] your question and add it to tags, so that others can find it.

Comment: ahh, react.js I use